# How to run whole of the sql statement in the UDF or in the loop in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I am trying to iterate couple of bigquery SQL statement which basically returns the non-scaler dataset(returns about 10 columns with 200 records). The sql query looks like something like this

```
with aa as 
          (select * from mytable
            .....................),

            ab as 
( Select * from aa where not IN (select some_field from aa where somefield <> "some string"(parameter from function)) 
    JOIN bb 
    ...............)
     Select * from ab
```

I am trying to run the above code as function with different parameters with some loop kind of functionality and union the result of each iteration as a single table output. I have tried using the UDF function not sure how can I put that above code/sql statements that basically runs on the bigquery and use them as iteratively. In simple words i want something like this

```
1. Declare array for the parameters to be passed in the function on the step 2
2. Make function of (my_sql_query_that_accepts_the_argument_from_this_function)
3. Iterate the function in step2 number of times the items in declared Array step1
4. Union the results every iteration and gives the output finally as Bigquery output.
```

any thoughts would be appreciated or if there is smarter way to do that.

Here would be the closest example

Hello sorry for not being very absolute. Here is the example

```
With table as
(
Select 1 as accnt_number, 20 as revenue, 'aaa' as product, date('2020-01-01') as date, date('2020-01-01') as start_date
UNION ALL
Select 2 as accnt_number, 22 as revenue, 'bbb' as product, date('2020-01-15') as date, date('2019-01-01') as start_date
UNION ALL
Select 3 as accnt_number, 22 as revenue, 'ccc' as product, date('2020-03-21') as date, date('2020-01-01') as start_date
UNION ALL
Select 2 as accnt_number, 22 as revenue, 'aaa' as product, date('2020-02-11') as date, date('2020-01-01') as start_date
UNION ALL
Select 2 as accnt_number, 22 as revenue, 'bbb' as product, date('2020-06-01') as date, date('2020-01-01') as start_date
UNION ALL
Select 2 as accnt_number, 22 as revenue, 'ddd' as product, date('2020-04-01') as date, date('2020-01-01') as start_date
),

results as ( --  This logic doesn't make any sense just writing it down to give the feel of how it will be in main query i am trying to use.

Select  first.* from table first
join table second
on first.accnt_number = second.accnt_number AND first.product = 'aaa' -- <-this needs to be the changed everytime the loop runs with products in some kind of variable (1)
   And first.date between date_add(second.date, INTERVAL -7 day) AND date_add(second.date, INTERVAL +7 day)

)

Select * from results  -- Results of this needs to be iterated everytime with new product name from variable as mentioned in (1), UNIONioning ALL ultimately to give the final result for each product name in the loop.

-- So basically all of the above sql query needs to be run again and again ie number of times as the length of the array holding the product names(aaa,bbb...) at (1) and then results get union all at the end of each iteration of the loop
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem well. Can you state a running query, sample input, and desired results?

Comment: AS @FelipeHoffa said, you should provide those details. So we can help you better.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying back I have edited the question.

Comment: @Mr.Mahajan, can you describe why you need loop the query with the amount of elements inside products? Also, wouldn't it be more feasible to run an schedule query everyday in case you want to update a view or a table with the desired columns from a table?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes I am actually going to use the aftermath of the query in the dashboard report in data studio or some other visualisation software where user can simply select the product from the drop down or something and filters the result from the table that will be created after the repeated loop for each product.

Comment: Can you explain the loop logic , how will first.product will change each iteration?

Comment: I was thinking if there is some scripting i could use some array variable to hold the distinct results of the ```select distinct product from table``` and the use that to iterate over the results section. Ultimately Unioning all the results.

Comment: I was trying to think of a script for you. However, I don't understand how you want your `first.product` to change in your ON statement and the reason why. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: So basically when the ``` select distinct product from table ``` will run it will produce the sccaler results and save the result of it in a variable holding array lets say product_array and then i can use that product_array in the place of the ON first.product  = product_array.  I was thinking maybe with some scripting I can run the whole SQL query again and again picking product_array and embedding that at the place of ON first.product =  'aaa' (see the code).  Ultimately Unioning the results for each iteration of the product in the product array.